# ArcGIS javascript API: A way to position Dynamic Service layer on top of Graphic Layer?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have 3 layers:

1. Tiled based map
2. DynamicServiceLayer with ~1000 points
3. Graphics layer with ~20 polygons

I really need the DynamicServiceLayer to be on top of the graphics layer (point must be on top of polygons), but I think it might not be possible - does the graphics layer always draw on top of all other layers?  I tried to reorderLayers without success.

Anyone drawn a dynamic service on top of a graphics layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Graphics layers and feature layers are always drawn on top of tiled and dynamic services. It is not possible to put a dynamic layer on top of a graphics or feature layer.

Have you tried displaying your point data as a feature layer? You could then put your point feature layer on top of your polygon graphics layer.

Comment: The problem is that I'm getting terrible performance in IE 8 when mapping ~1000 point in a graphic or feature layer.  We decided to cluster the graphics...that solved the poor IE performance mostly.  Hopefully the client likes clustering...

Comment: Do you have a link to your app? I'm curious to see how you implemented clustering.